# Azure: error not detected

Tags: azure, azure-debugger

I have an experiment in Azure. When I launch the run I obtain:

[image]

If you look at the top on the right you see that there is an error, but no module has it.
If I run the single module where (in this simple case) I know that the error has to be, I can highlight the specific error.

[image]

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error once when, for some reason, a module (not created by me) was simply under another one. So the error was shown, but I couldn't see that module.